# How can i use bit operation to represent more than one switch by one byte without lock in c?

Tags: c, linux, locking, shared-memory

There is a situation, I need to represent 32 switch status with 4 bytes shared memory(each one bit for a switch), and there will be more than one process update it with some operation like '| & ^'(each process in charge of different switch), I know that it is ok if I store those switch in different memory address without lock, but could I do it without any lock in the same memory address.

Comment: This is what operations like compare and swap are for.

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to do it. GCC provided a lot of API associated with this target. [ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html)

Comment: I'm curious: what is it about your system that makes it OK to handle each '_switch in different memory address without lock_' ?

Comment: @ChrisHall, I mean that store each switch flag in a consequent address of shared memory, it is not necessary locking in anyone system I think, because it does not exist any critical resource.

Comment: So what happens if two processes try to toggle (that is `switch[i] ^= 1`, assuming each switch is always `0` or `1`) a switch at the same time ?

Comment: @ChrisHall I am sorry for not providing the detail information of my question(I will update it), it will not update the same bit in two different bit at the same time, I switch to this method to avoid iterate a list and check that flag one by one.

Comment: So you could have two processes updating different bits in a byte, at the same time ?  Unless you only have one CPU (one hardware thread of execution), it is hard to see how you could get away without using an atomic read-modify-write operation to update a bit.

Comment: Yes，I did used gcc __sycn_fetch_and like api，and the result seems not bad.